# How to check which stored procedure/function inserts/deletes/updates data to particular table with time stamp in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to check which stored procedure/function inserts/deletes/updates data to particular table with time stamp in SQL server.

I can get list of stored procedure(SP) and function that has table name in its body. but those Sp's or functions may or may not be calling the particular table

Please suggest.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the relevance of the words "with time stamp" is meant to be. If the table was "without time stamp" (whatever that means), why do you think the answer would be fundamentally different?

Comment: Also.. "I  can get list of stored procedure(SP) and function that has table name in its body" vs "may or may not be calling the particular table". How can the table be there and "may not be calling"? Although you don't call tables, so I assume you mean insert / update.

Comment: @JamesZ - because the stored procedure could contain a line like `--We used to use TableFoz but don't anymore` or the *literal* string of characters making up the table name may be a subset of other object names, as just two examples.

Comment: We created SP's to do insert/delete/update on table but some SP's other than our SP's using direct queries to insert/delete/update our table data. We need to check.

Comment: @JamesZ some SP's are old and not using. Need which SP did insert/delete/update on particular table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Need which SP did insert/delete/update on table with time.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check which stored procedure/function inserts/deletes/updates data to particular table with time stamp in SQL server.

There is way to find tables which are modified ,but you cant get who did it

So below are the only ways

1.Enable Audit /extended events
2.Modify proc to insert data into some table with some checks like

```
  tablename  procname modifieddate
```